# Displaying info on the same page from a side bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

My project has a sidebar that has four different options. (Schedule, progress, add course, drop course).

I want users to be able to click on these options (after expanding the side bar) and display the information from which ever of the four they clicked. I want this information to display on the same page, not link to another page.

I have done this before by having invisible pages and using a showpage function.  This time around though it is coded differently with classes.

Note: I don't have any data for these 4 pages now - I just want to set it up so they function.

To keep it short: What code I need and where to display information (Ex: "Here is your schedule") on the same page when Schedule is clicked?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>STUDENT SCHEDULER APP</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ssaStyles.css">

<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(function() {
  console.log("jQuery was loaded");
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  function toggleSidebar() {
    $(".button").toggleClass("active");
    $("main").toggleClass("move-to-left");
    $(".sidebar-item").toggleClass("active");
  }

  $(".button").on("click tap", function() {
    toggleSidebar();
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      toggleSidebar();
    }
  });

  });

    </script>

   </head>

  <body>

<div id="header">
  <h1>Welcome!</h1>
</div>

<div class="nav-right visible-xs">
  <div class="button" id="btn">
   <div class="bar top"></div>
   <div class="bar middle"></div>
   <div class="bar bottom"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- nav-right -->
<main>


  <nav>
    <div class="nav-right hidden-xs">
     <div class="button" id="btn">
    <div class="bar top"></div>
    <div class="bar middle"></div>
    <div class="bar bottom"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- nav-right -->
  </nav>


</main>

 <div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="sidebar-list">
   <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Schedule</a>
</li>
 <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Progress</a>
</li>
<li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Add a course</a>
</li>
<li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Drop a 
course</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 </body>

 </html>
```

I am a beginner.